permutation group on $\mathbb{F}_p$
Suppose $\mathbb{F}_p$ the field with $p$ elements and $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ the permutation group. Define for $a \in \mathbb{F}^\times_p$ and $b \in \mathbb{F}_p$ the permutation $\gamma_{a,b}: \mathbb{F}_p \to \mathbb{F}_p, x \to ax+b$. The set of all such permutations forms a subgroup for $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ we call $AGL(1, \mathbb{F}_p)$ We were asked to show that the set $\{\sigma \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{F}_p) \mid \sigma^{-1}\langle\gamma_{1,1}\rangle \sigma = \langle\gamma_{1,1}\rangle\}$ equals $AGL(1, \mathbb{F}_p)$. I've already showed that $AGL(1, \mathbb{F}_p)\subseteq \{\sigma \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{F}_p) \mid \sigma^{-1}\langle\gamma_{1,1}\rangle \sigma = \langle\gamma_{1,1}\rangle\}$ by showing $\langle\gamma_{1,1}\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $AGL(1, \mathbb{F}_p)$. It's the other inclusion I am having some trouble with. I was thinking with contraposition but I don't know how to characterize elements that aren't in  $AGL(1, \mathbb{F}_p)$ apart from a fairly abstract cykel notation. Any tips?

Have you written $\gamma_{1,1}$ (and its powers) in the cycle notation? Do you remember how you get $\sigma^{-1}\gamma_{1,1}\sigma$ in cycle notation? Can you show that the non-trivial powers of $\gamma_{1,1}$ are conjugate already in the affine linear group? Can you show that $\sigma^{-1}\gamma_{1,1}\sigma=\gamma_{1,1}$ only when $\sigma$ is a power of $\gamma_{1,1}$? How could you combine these pieces.

Mind you, this exact same exercise has been handled on our site already, possibly many times. Under the guise of normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_p$. That's why I'm not posting an answer. You can search the site with those buzzwords, but... are you familiar with Sylow theory?

We haven't seen Sylow theory yet. But it's coming up after the easter break.

Too bad. Then this thread may be all Greek to you. And this need not help either?

And to answer your question/hints: yes, no, do you mean that the powers of $\gamma_{1,1}$ are of the form $\gamma_{1,c}$ cause in that case yes and no I don't see what you mean

No I don't really understand those threads

Ok, so you know that $\gamma_{1,1}=(012\ldots,p-1)$. You can also try to use the fact then $\sigma\gamma_{1,1}\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(0),\sigma(1),\ldots)$, where on the right I mean the cycle notation even though I use comma separators. The plots of elements of $AGL$ are lines on the plane $\Bbb{F}_p^2$. Two points determine a line etc.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In any case, this is only correct when $p$ is prime. It is false when $p=4$ for example.

We can show the inclusion
$$
\{\sigma\in\mathcal S(\mathbb F_p)\mid\sigma^{-1}\langle\gamma_{1,1}\rangle\sigma=\langle\gamma_{1,1}\rangle\}\subseteq\mathit{AGL}(\mathbb F_p)
$$
by the following easy computation.
Let $\sigma\in\mathcal S(\mathbb F_p)$ with $\sigma ^{-1}\langle\gamma_{1,1}\rangle\sigma= \langle\gamma_{1,1}\rangle$.
Then we have, in particular, $\gamma_{1,1}\in \sigma ^{-1}\langle\gamma_{1,1}\rangle\sigma$, so $\gamma_{1,1}=\sigma ^{-1}\gamma_{1,a}\sigma$ for some $a\in\mathbb F_p^\times$ (checking $a\ne0$ is easy).
This means that $\sigma\gamma_{1,1}=\gamma_{1,a}\sigma$, and thus $\sigma(x+1)=\sigma(x)+a$ for all $x\in\mathbb F_p$.
Hence, letting $b=\sigma(0)$, we can see that $\sigma(x)=ax+b$ inductively on $x$.
